# Measure network consumption per program and month

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

I'm looking for a permanently-running monitor which can emit a monthly (or daily, etc) bandwidth report, in a per-program manner.
Example desired output:

```
Bandwidth consumption: last 30 days
==============
Program     Downloaded   Uploaded
/usr/bin/ssh  30MB       100MB
/usr/bin/java 9000MB     3000MB
```

(it also could be per-process instead of per-program, but then I'd have to consolidate entries manually)

After significative research (including many similar questions over Stack Exchange), I still haven't found such a monitor. Maybe this is not possible under Linux. Or maybe this is bit of an unusual need.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nethogs -t` to capture per-process usage and parse the output.
From https://boopathi.in/blog/capturing-per-process-bandwidth-usage-using-nethogs/

```
sh -ic "{ /usr/sbin/nethogs -t eth1 &> output; \
kill 0; } | { sleep $TIMEOUT; \
kill 0; }" 3>&1 2>/dev/null
```

The output fields are:

```
Process / Process id / User id    sent kbps    recv kbps
```

and parse the output using https://github.com/boopathi/nethogs-parser

Another solution from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705080/3812704

But I like the first solution better.

Comment: Nethogs creates many files because I'm using ppp0 so I need to sum process usage in each file that is impossible for month. Is there any solution to do that for me?

Comment: @Daniyal Please ask a new question and provide a nethogs sample output in it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to accumulate and process the `netstat` or `iptraf` manually in some shell with manual `sort`ing.

Most of the monitors in linux are runtime, some are enlisted [here](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/).